# Abstraction over different OR Mapping frameworks

Tags: hibernate, ibatis

The Data access layer of my product today uses Hibernate as the OR mapping framework.In future would like to use other frameworks like iBatis.

1. What is the best way to design such an abstraction layer on top of these OR mapping frameworks ?
2. Is there any such framework already available ?
3. I want to design such a system where with simple configuration changes I should be able to switch between these OR frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think adding an abstraction on top of hibernate / ibatis makes sense. They are quite different frameworks -  even if you are able to create a common api - it will leave out the meta-data part (on which your code is much more dependent on). You should think really hard about why you need it and what it will look like.  [Already people are complaining about too many levels of abstractions](http://search.vimeo.com/28885655) - adding more only makes things more difficult.

A better solution would be to isolate most of your domain logic from depending on the persistence / transaction / security etc (Domain Driven Design).  That way you might be able to preserve the important parts of the application logic if you have to change the implementation of one of them.

Take a look at [spring-data](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data)  it is different than the kind of abstraction that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I am right now thinking about JPA. Hibernate already supports JPA. Not sure about iBatis. From standards perspective it looks good to me. JPA can be the abstraction i am looking for. Any thoughts ?

Comment: JPA is almost the same as Hibernate (in terms of abstraction level) - just a standardized API.  No - iBatis doesn't support JPA. EclipseLink, OpenJPA etc are some other implementations. There is also a limited implementation of JPA for google app engine, amazon simpledb etc..  Yes it is better to use JPA 2.0 with hibernate as a provider today instead of direct Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that iBatis is not ORM framework, while Hibernate is. Point of iBatis is to map concrete SQL statements to objects, while Hibernate tries to solve object-relational mapping (and mismatch) in more abstract way.

Few years ago, subset of core features of Hibernate has been standardized to JPA. It makes sense to do things JPA-way (so you can switch JPA vendor - Hibernate, EclipseLink, ObjectDB).

However, it doesn't make much sense building some abstraction on top of different approaches (like Hibernate vs iBatis).

Answer (score 0):

First, I absolutely agree with Xorty's reply concerning iBatis vs. Hibernate frameworks.

Except one thing. You may consider switching between iBatis, Hibernate.
I would recommend you to read `iBatis In Action` book, chapters 10, 11. You'll find there an example of iBatis configuration that let you to configure/use both iBatis and Hibernate with DAO pattern and its implementations by iBatis sql map files, Hibernate and JDBC.